# Sincronizar banco MySQL com XLS

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, xls

A situação é a seguinte.
Tenho um banco de dados MYSQL e um Arquivo XLS em um servidor FTP
O código abaixo faz o download do XLS a leitura e a o UPDATE dos no banco a partir dos dados XLS.

O problema é que ele atualiza apenas os dados existentes, preciso verificar no banco MYSQL se todas as ID's do XLS existem e caso não existam faça um outro tipo de query, dando insert com os dados dessa nova linha do XLS.

Segue o código em https://paste.ofcode.org/Vjt78dH5vwCLfDvQf3EbQq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem duas abordagens possiveis: usar a função [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.affected-rows.php) ou usar a clausula [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) do mysql.

## Usando a função `mysqli_affected_rows`

Basicamente, após cada update, você verifica se alguma linha foi modificada no banco. Se tiver sido modificada é por que o registro já existia no banco e foi atualizado. Caso contrario, o registro não existia no banco e você pode fazer um insert. Você precisa apenas checar isso com um if. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
// ALTERA NOME e DESCRIÇÃO
mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE ps_product_lang SET name = '$name',
description_short = '$desc_short' WHERE id_product = '$id_product'");

//nenhum registro foi alterado no banco, então faz um insert
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) < 1){
    //faça o insert
    mysqli_query($conexao, 'insert into nome_tabela (campos) 
    values (valores)');
}
```

## Usando a clausula ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Nessa abordagem, você precisa ter um campo único na sua tabela (chave primaria ou unique, por exemplo), para que você tente fazer primeiro o insert e se falhar (o registro já existe) você faz o update. É como o exemplo anterior, só que ao contrario e feito em sql. Exemplo:

```
mysqli_query($conexao, 'INSERT INTO nome_tabela (campo1, campo2,
campo3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
campo2=valor2, campo3=valor3 WHERE campo1=valor1);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Ambas soluções funcionaram perfeitamente. Optei por usar  mysqli_affected_rows para poder manipular melhor o insert que quero fazer.